# Load relationships before foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a `User` model that does have many Networks. Each `Network` does have many Lists.
I have this code in the `User` model that is really slow:

```
foreach ($this->networks as $network) {
    if ($myCondition) {
        foreach ($network->lists()->get()->lists('id')->toArray() as $newId) {
            $ids[] = $newId;
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to load all lists of all networks before the 2 foreach loops.

Comment: Please define in your title the language/technology have used. Thanks. Read mode in: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This may speed it up, although I'm not certain:

```
$this->networks()->with('lists')->get()->pluck('lists')->flatten()->pluck('id')
```

Also if it isn't a many to many relationship you could consider putting user_id as a column in your 'lists' table if speed is really important

Answer (score 1):

This is lazy eager loading:

```
$this->networks->load('lists');
```

That loaded the `lists` relationship for all the networks.

If you just want this list of ids and don't need the actual records returned you can do that as well:

```
$ids = Lists::whereHas('network', function ($query) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $this->networks->pluck('id'));
})->pluck('id');
```

If you want because Lists belongsTo Network you can go around the relationship:

```
$ids = Lists::whereIn('network_id', $this->networks->pluck('id'))
    ->pluck('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep code in User model. In controller, you can do:

```
$User->load('networks', function($q){
    $q->with('lists');
});
```

There in:

'networks' and 'lists' is your relationship name.

Further:
You can lazy load all your relation ship, in child by child.

```
$User->load('networks', function($q){
    $q->with('lists', function($q1){
         $q1->with('child_relationship_of_lists');
    });
});
```